# props children react js is not defined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Im new in react, i dont know how to fix the error. You can visit this codesandbox for the error. Thanks before.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-perlman-lku1qb?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to pass in the props as parameter to the `LayoutComponent`.

```
const LayoutComponent = (props) => {
  const { Content } = Layout;

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Layout>
        <Layout style={{ padding: "0 24px 24px" }}>
          <Breadcrumb style={{ margin: "16px 0" }}>
            <Breadcrumb.Item>Home</Breadcrumb.Item>
            <Breadcrumb.Item>List</Breadcrumb.Item>
            <Breadcrumb.Item>App</Breadcrumb.Item>
          </Breadcrumb>
          <Content
            className="site-layout-background"
            style={{
              padding: 24,
              margin: 0,
              minHeight: 500
            }}
          >
            {props.children}
          </Content>
        </Layout>
      </Layout>
    </Layout>
  );
};
export default LayoutComponent;
```

Comment: Ohh god, i forgot about that. Thanks for the answer @Palladium02